# Printing row using ForeachWriter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, foreach

I am reading incoming data stream from a kafka topic using apache spark (Scala). I want to print each row from the message. I am trying to use `ForeachWriter` and my code looks like:

```
DF.writeStream.foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row] {
  
override def process(value: Row): Unit = {
  println(s"Processing ${value}")
  println(value.toString())
}
override def open(partitionId: Long, epochId: Long): Boolean = {true}

override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {}
}
).start()
```

But I am not getting any output on the console. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to achieve your required result.

1. Using ForeachWriter, whatever you did is correct but you missed calling awaitTermination() method in the end.
2. Using foreachBatch

code:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

import spark.implicits._

val kafkaDF = spark.readStream
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        .option("subscribe", "mytopic")
        .option("startingOffsets", "latest") 
        .load().select('value.cast("string"))

 // Any one approach can be used at a time

 // 1. using ForeachWriter
     
   kafkaDF.writeStream.foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row] {
    override def process(value: Row): Unit = println(s"Processing ${value}")
    override def open(partitionId: Long, epochId: Long): Boolean = true
    override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {}
}
).start().awaitTermination()

// 2. using foreachBatch
kafkaDF.writeStream.foreachBatch((ds, l) => {
    ds.foreach(println(_))
}).start().awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Hey I tried this on Azure databricks notebook, but It got stuck at the command with message `Running command`. Then I run the job by building the package, I got nothing on the `stdout` and log4j logs gave a message saying:

`Writing atomically to dbfs:/tmp/temporary-43090881-025b-4f0b-9d94-abde87b5bddb/metadata using temp file dbfs:/tmp/temporary-43090881-025b-4f0b-9d94-abde87b5bddb/__tmp_path_dir/.metadata.370ee7c6-aeb8-4c87-9b24-a3f61ea103f6.tmp`